# Django request.body format

Tags: django, request

When I try to print request.body,
the below is printed

```
b'----------------------------914826831994362856243559\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="release_date"\r\n\r\n2003-06-01\r\n----------------------------914826831994362856243559\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="fanmodel"\r\n\r\nfan234code\r\n----------------------------914826831994362856243559\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="country_code"\r\n\r\nAO\r\n----------------------------914826831994362856243559--\r\n'
```

My post request data is available here but along with a lot other data.
I want to understand what is that other data and how can I format it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using django, you can access the POST data with `request.POST.get('variable_name')`

Read more:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/

Answer (score 0):

What you see is **bytestring** of the raw HTTP request body - see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body). To retrieve data try to use request.POST or request.GET attribute.